# How to convert a queryset in django to json

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I´ve seen his question has been answered multiple times for django < 2.xx, but for the current version I am using (2.1) I´been unable to convert my querysets to a json format. I´ve tried serializer using the django rest framework, but so far the only use I was able to implement is to serialize a model, so when my querysets has results from different models that does not work.

This has beeing really annoying, In frameworks as Laravel this is supposed to be pretty simple, I would appreciate any help.

```
class Medic(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    validated = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    qualification = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    profesional_license = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # add additional fields in here
    first_name2 = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)
    last_name2 = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)
    dni = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cell = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    city_id = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

And a query example:

```
medic = Medic.objects.filter(
            user_id__city_id=comercial.city_id).select_related('user_id').values()
```

Comment: With a Serializer, you can serialize it with `MySerializer(queryset, many=True)`.

Comment: Do you have any code for us to look at?

Comment: Or with python module `json`

Comment: When you say "my querysets has results from different models" how do you mean?

Comment: Hold on, a *queryset* with *different* models?

Comment: Probably nested relationships, but it would be nice to see some model code to confirm

Comment: So yeah, e.g. If I use select_related() I should get a inner join like result, that data is the one I like to serialize

Comment: The [django serialization topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/serialization/)

Answer (score 6):

*I´ve tried serializer using the Django rest framework*, You don't need rest-framework for serializing a QuerySet, you can:

```
# This is according to your example, I, really can't imagine 
#, why you're saying you have a queryset having results from
# different models. If you're using QuerySet.union, or some similar
# feature, serialize QuerySets before join them.
from django.core.serializers import json

medic = Medic.objects.filter(
            user_id__city_id=comercial.city_id).select_related('user_id')

json_serializer = json.Serializer()
json_serialized = json_serializer.serialize(medic)
```

Comment: What are the negatives of merely using django's serializer?

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two problems you want to tackle:

1. serializing data of a *relation* (the `OneToOneField`); and
2. serializing *multiple* elements.

The first problem is solved by specifying the serializer of the related model, like:

```
class CustomUserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'

class CustomUserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    user = CustomUserSerializer(source='user_id', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Medic
        fields = '__all__'
```

If you have build a serializer `MedicSerializer` for the `Medic` model, you can serialize it by setting the `many=...` parameter to `True`.

For example:

```
def some_view(request):
    queryset = Medic.objects.filter(
        user_id__city_id=comercial.city_id
      ).select_related('user_id')
    serializer = MedicSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return JSONResponse({'data': serializer.data})  # the data, now JSON encoded
```

> **Note**: a `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField`, etc. typically do *not* end with an `_id` suffix, since the relation itself is a lazy reference to a model object, not to its primary key value.